# Reducing String Size By Zipping And Storing In Object

Tags: c#

Our application at work basically has to create over a million objects each night to run a numerical simulation involving some weather observations that were recorded during the day.

Each object contains a few string properties (and one very large xml property - About 2 MB) - Beacuse of the size of the large xml property we dont load this up and instead prefer to go the database when we need access to this xml blob (which we do for each object)

I was wondering if it makes sense to somehow retrieve the xml data (which is 2MB) compress it in memory and store it in the object - This prevents us having to do a database query for each object when we come to process it.

I would much rather zip the data, store it in the object and at processing time, unzip and process

Is it possible to zip a string in process and how can I do this without creating millions of MemoryStreams / zip streams for each object?

Comment: Is the XML different per each object?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that compression is not a good idea - it adds quite an overhead to processing, which already appears to be quite intensive.

Perhaps a light-weight format would be better - JSON or a binary serialized object representing the data.

Without more detail, it is difficult to give a definite answer, or better options.

Comment: I have no control over the XML - Its required and I cant change that - Would be interested to see if I can binary seriliase the XML string but I think its better to simply compress

Comment: I wouldn't try to binary serialize XML. I meant create an object in the shape of your data and binary serialize that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) which has a simple API so you can do something like this:

```
byte[] compressedProperty;
public string MyProperty
{
    get { DeflateStream.UncompressString(compressedProperty); }
    set { compressedProperty = DeflateStream.CompressString(value); }
}
```

Not sure if it will work out performance wise for you though.

**Update**:
I only know the `GZipStream` and the `DeflateStream` class. Neither of them expose a `string` interface. Even DotNetZip uses a stream under the hood when you call the functions above, it's just wrapped around a nice interface (which you could do with the `System.IO.Compression` classes on your own). Not sure what your problem is with streams.
 If you really want to avoid streams then you probably have to roll your own compression. [Here is a guy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2008/05/05/huffman-coding-with-f.aspx) who rolled a simple Huffman encoder to encode strings in F#. Don't know how well it works but I you want to avoid 3rd party libs and streams then you could give it a crack.

Comment: Is there anything like this in the BCL library?  Does .NET allow zipping of strings in place without using streams?